# I have a question about using crontab in bash

Tags: bash, cron

I have a problem.
Why this code, it does not work.

1. I got path '/home/LLIN/Documents/FT/Report' by using (pwd).
2. I set to the script the time 8:30AM every day.

> ```
> 30 8 * * * cd /home/LLIN/Documents/FT/Report;node final.js
> ```

Comment: What error messages are you getting?  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged

Comment: it does not error message just the script it does not execute!!

Comment: Try putting a test/dummy job in cron, like `echo hello > ~/myfile.txt` and see if that works or not.  Then try a dummy job like `ls file-does-not-exist` and see if you see the error message (hint: it goes to the MAILTO email address configured in cron, make sure you configure one!).